# Error Couldn't read row 0, col 5 from CursorWindow sqlite CRUD

Tags: android, android-studio, sqllite

Estaba iniciando mi app para hacer la conexion y retornar la lista con los datos de el objeto y me arroja ese error alguna solucion para poder proseguir con mi app?

2018-11-11 22:04:55.122 4942-4942/? E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.proyecto.pizzaappproyect, PID: 4942
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.proyecto.pizzaappproyect/com.example.proyecto.pizzaappproyect.MainActivity}: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Couldn't read row 0, col 5 from CursorWindow.  Make sure the Cursor is initialized correctly before accessing data from it.
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2668)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2729)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1480)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6169)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:891)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:781)
     Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Couldn't read row 0, col 5 from CursorWindow.  Make sure the Cursor is initialized correctly before accessing data from it.
        at android.database.CursorWindow.nativeGetLong(Native Method)
        at android.database.CursorWindow.getLong(CursorWindow.java:511)
        at android.database.CursorWindow.getInt(CursorWindow.java:578)
        at android.database.AbstractWindowedCursor.getInt(AbstractWindowedCursor.java:69)
        at com.example.proyecto.pizzaappproyect.DB.CRUD.pizzaList(CRUD.java:108)
        at com.example.proyecto.pizzaappproyect.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:59)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6692)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1118)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2621)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2729) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1480) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6169) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:891) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:781)

```
public List<Pizza> pizzaList() {
    List<Pizza> list = new ArrayList<>();
    db = helper.getReadableDatabase();
    String sql = "select * from " + ConexionHelper.TABLE;
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(sql, null);

    while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
        Pizza p = new Pizza();
        p.id = cursor.getString(0);
        p.nombre = cursor.getString(1);
        p.foto1 = cursor.getInt(2);
        p.igrediente1=cursor.getInt(3);
        p.igrediente2=cursor.getInt(4);
        p.igrediente3=cursor.getInt(5); // esta es la que arroja el error
        p.igrediente4=cursor.getInt(6);
        p.calificacion=cursor.getInt(7);
        p.descripcion = cursor.getString(8);
        p.precio = cursor.getInt(9);
        list.add(p);
    }
    db.close();

    return list;

}
```

**CRUD**

```
public class CRUD {
private ConexionHelper helper;
private ContentValues values;
private SQLiteDatabase db;


public CRUD(Context context) {
    helper = new ConexionHelper(context);
    values = new ContentValues();
}

public void insert(Pizza p) {
    db = helper.getWritableDatabase();
    values.clear();
    values.put(ConexionHelper.NOMBRE, p.nombre);
    values.put(ConexionHelper.FOTO, p.foto1);
    values.put(ConexionHelper.INGREDIENTE1, p.igrediente1);
    values.put(ConexionHelper.INGREDIENTE2, p.igrediente2);
    values.put(ConexionHelper.INGREDIENTE3, p.igrediente3);
    values.put(ConexionHelper.INGREDIENTE4, p.igrediente4);
    values.put(ConexionHelper.CALIFICACION, p.calificacion);
    values.put(ConexionHelper.DESCRIPCION, p.descripcion);
    values.put(ConexionHelper.PRECIO, p.precio);

    db.insert(ConexionHelper.TABLE, null, values);
    db.close();
}

public void delete(String id) {
    String pk = id + "";
    db = helper.getWritableDatabase();
    db.delete(ConexionHelper.TABLE,
            ConexionHelper.ID + "=?",
            new String[]{pk});
    db.close();
}

public void update(Pizza p) {
    db = helper.getWritableDatabase();
    values.clear();
    values.put(ConexionHelper.NOMBRE, p.nombre);
    values.put(ConexionHelper.FOTO, p.foto1);
    values.put(ConexionHelper.INGREDIENTE1, p.igrediente1);
    values.put(ConexionHelper.INGREDIENTE2, p.igrediente2);
    values.put(ConexionHelper.INGREDIENTE3, p.igrediente3);
    values.put(ConexionHelper.INGREDIENTE4, p.igrediente4);
    values.put(ConexionHelper.CALIFICACION, p.calificacion);
    values.put(ConexionHelper.DESCRIPCION, p.descripcion);
    values.put(ConexionHelper.PRECIO, p.precio);

    String pk = p.id + "";//String.valueOf(m.id);
    db.update(ConexionHelper.TABLE,
            values,
            ConexionHelper.ID + "=?",
            new String[]{pk});

    db.close();
}

public Pizza find(String id) {
    Pizza p = new Pizza();
    db = helper.getReadableDatabase();
    String sql = "select * from " + ConexionHelper.TABLE + " where " + ConexionHelper.ID + "=?";
    String pk = id + "";
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(sql, new String[]{pk});

    if (cursor.moveToNext()) {
        p.id = cursor.getString(0);
        p.nombre = cursor.getString(1);
        p.foto1 = cursor.getInt(2);
        p.igrediente1 = cursor.getInt(3);
        p.igrediente2 = cursor.getInt(4);
        p.igrediente3 = cursor.getInt(5);
        p.igrediente4 = cursor.getInt(6);
        p.calificacion = cursor.getInt(7);
        p.descripcion = cursor.getString(8);
        p.precio = cursor.getInt(9);
    }
    db.close();
    return p;
}

public List<Pizza> pizzaList() {
    List<Pizza> list = new ArrayList<>();
    db = helper.getReadableDatabase();
    String sql = "select * from " + ConexionHelper.TABLE;
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(sql, null);

    while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
        Pizza p = new Pizza();
        p.id = cursor.getString(0);
        p.nombre = cursor.getString(1);
        p.foto1 = cursor.getInt(2);
        p.igrediente1 = cursor.getInt(3);
        p.igrediente2 = cursor.getInt(4);
        p.igrediente3 = cursor.getInt(5);
        p.igrediente4 = cursor.getInt(6);
        p.calificacion = cursor.getInt(7);
        p.descripcion = cursor.getString(8);
        p.precio = cursor.getInt(9);

        list.add(p);
    }
    db.close();

    return list;

}
```

}

**HELPER**

```
public class ConexionHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
public static final String DATABASE_NAME = "data";
private static final int VERSION = 1;


public static final String TABLE = "pizza";
public static final String ID = "id";
public static final String NOMBRE = "nombre";
public static final String FOTO = "foto1";
public static final String INGREDIENTE1 = "igrediente1";
public static final String INGREDIENTE2 = "igrediente2";
public static final String INGREDIENTE3 = "igrediente3";
public static final String INGREDIENTE4 = "igrediente4";
public static final String CALIFICACION = "calificacion";
public static final String DESCRIPCION = "descripcion";
public static final String PRECIO = "precio";

public ConexionHelper(Context context) {
    super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, VERSION);
}


@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    String script = "";
    script += "create table " + TABLE + "(";
    script += ID + " integer primary key autoincrement,";
    script += NOMBRE + " text,";
    script += FOTO + " text,";
    script += INGREDIENTE1 + " text,";
    script += INGREDIENTE2 + " text,";
    script += INGREDIENTE3 + " text,";
    script += INGREDIENTE4 + " text,";
    script += CALIFICACION + " integer";
    script += DESCRIPCION + " text,";
    script += PRECIO + " integer";
    script += ");";
    db.execSQL(script);
    db.execSQL("insert into " + TABLE + " values( 'Española',"+ R.drawable.pizza_espanola+" , "+R.drawable.espa_ola1+" , "+R.drawable.espa_ola2+"  , "+R.drawable.espa_ola3+"  , "+R.drawable.espa_ola4+"  ,5, 'ÑAMI ÑAMI',7500);");
    db.execSQL("insert into " + TABLE + " values( 'Todas Las Carnes'," + R.drawable.todascarne + "," + R.drawable.todas1 + "," + R.drawable.todas2 + " ," + R.drawable.todas3 + " ," + R.drawable.todas4 + " ,4, 'DELICHIUSS',5500);");
    db.execSQL("insert into " + TABLE + " values( 'Vegetariana'," + R.drawable.vegetariana + "," + R.drawable.veg1 + "," + R.drawable.veg2 + " ," + R.drawable.veg3 + " ," + R.drawable.veg4 + " ,3, 'KAKAKAK',1500);");




}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    db.execSQL("drop table " + TABLE);
    onCreate(db);
}
```

}

Comment: Hola Renan , siempre sucede el error al leer el campo de indice 5?

Comment: Hola Jorgesys, si me tira en esa linea de error segun el Logcat mas dicho lo alcanza a leer ni la columna 0

Comment: Adjunte el Crud para que lo revise

Comment: Elimina la aplicación o elimina su cache , revisa la info en mi respuestra @RenanMatias

Answer (score 1):

De acuerdo a el mensaje de error:

> IllegalStateException: Couldn't read row 0, col 5 from CursorWindow.
>   Make sure the Cursor is initialized correctly before accessing data
>   from it.

Se puede determinar que tu Cursor en realidad tiene unicamente 5 campos, debes revisar el select para obtener la informacion necesaria.

Al parecer la tabla `ConexionHelper.TABLE`, unicamente contiene 5 campos.

```
  String sql = "select * from " + ConexionHelper.TABLE;
  Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(sql, null);
```

---

Revisando el script que realiza la creación de la tabla en realidad contiene mas de 5 campos, en este caso probablemente se creo una estructura incorrecta anteriormente, te recomiendo eliminar la aplicación o eliminar el cache para que se cree la correcta estructura de la tabla.